# Verify efficiently if all elements of one small arrayList are contained in another, several times

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I have several small arrayLists (800~1500) and for each one of those I must verify if it contains all items from a evaluation arrayList in the best possible time. Both the target arrayList (let's say, tSet) and the evaluation arrayList (eSet) have 1 to 5 elements.

I have tried a sequence of simple loops (current implementation), with a execution time of ~10 seonds, and containsAll(), with an inconsistent execution time ranging from 8 seconds to 16 seconds (using the same tSet). Is there a reason for this inconsistency? Is there a better way to perform this action?

Array elements are from the following class:

```
public class ItemBD_Temp implements Comparable<ItemBD_Temp> {
private String sTabela;
private String sValor;
private String sNome;
...
}
```

which also has a compareTo() method:

```
public int compareTo(ItemBD_Temp o) {
    String concatThis;
    String concatOther;
    if(this.sTabela.equals("*AnyTable*") || o.sTabela.equals("*AnyTable*")){
        concatThis = "";
        concatOther = "";
    }
    else if(this.sNome.equals("*AnyAtrib*") || o.sNome.equals("*AnyAtrib*")){
        concatThis = this.sTabela;
        concatOther = o.sTabela;
    }
    else if(this.sValor.equals("*AnyValue*") || o.sValor.equals("*AnyValue*")){
        concatThis = this.sTabela + this.sNome;
        concatOther = o.sTabela + o.sNome;
    }
    else{
        concatThis = this.sTabela + this.sNome + this.sValor;
        concatOther = o.sTabela + o.sNome + o.sValor;
    }

    return concatThis.compareTo(concatOther);
}
```

and this is a very simplified version of what I have so far:

```
for(int j = 0; j < eSet.itens.size() && tSetAllowed == true; j++){
    itemFound = false;
    //CURRENT ITEM TO BE SEARCHED
    eItem = new ItemBD_Temp(eSet.itens.get(j));

    //CHECK IF CURRENT ITEM IS ON THE CURRENT tSet. IF FOUND, STOPS AND CHECKS NEXT eItem
    for(int k = 0; k < tSet.size() && itemFound == false; k++){
        tItem = tSet.get(k);

        if(tItem.compareTo(eItem) == 0){
            itemFound = true;
        }
        else{
            itemFound = false;
        }
    }

    //IF tItem WASN'T FOUND, THEN tSet CAN BE DISCARTED
    if(itemFound==false){
        tSetAllowed = false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
In order to use arrayList.containsAll() I also had to override the Equals method, as follows:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 89 * hash + (this.sTabela != null ? this.sTabela.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 89 * hash + (this.sValor != null ? this.sValor.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 89 * hash + (this.sNome != null ? this.sNome.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
 }

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("OVERRIDED EQUALS");
        if (getClass() == obj.getClass()) {
            if(this.sTabela.equals("*AnyTable*") || ((ItemBD_Temp)obj).sTabela.equals("*AnyTable*")){
                return true;
            }
            else if(this.sNome.equals("*AnyAtrib*") || ((ItemBD_Temp)obj).sNome.equals("*AnyAtrib*")){
                if(this.sTabela.equals(((ItemBD_Temp)obj).sTabela))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            else if(this.sValor.equals("*AnyValue*") || ((ItemBD_Temp)obj).sValor.equals("*AnyValue*")){
                if((this.sTabela+this.sNome).equals( (((ItemBD_Temp)obj).sTabela+((ItemBD_Temp)obj).sNome) ))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            else{
                if((this.sTabela+this.sNome+this.sValor).equals( (((ItemBD_Temp)obj).sTabela+((ItemBD_Temp)obj).sNome+((ItemBD_Temp)obj).sValor) ))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            return (this == obj);
        }        
    }
```

This is needed because different objects like o`bj1 = {sTabela = "1", sNome = "2", sValor="3"}` and `obj2 = {sTabela = "AnyTable", sNome = "AnyAtrib", sValor="AnyValue"}` should be considered equivalent.

Comment: To perform a Set contains operations I suggest you use a Set. A HashSet.contains can be O(1) whereas List.contains is O(n).

Comment: @peter it's stronger than "can be" - it is (virtually) always O(1) provided the hashes have a reasonable distribution, which is the case for all JDK classes.

Comment: If you need to be able to both do O(1) contains() and iterate over them like a list in O(N) then you can use LinkedHashSet

Comment: @GeelHM Can you let us know what the constructor of ItemBD_Temp does? Would help a little bit, just in case.

Comment: @Elyasin The constructor simply receives 3 strings to create the object, as follows:

`public ItemBD_Temp(String sTabela, String sNome, String sValor) {
        this.setItemBD_Temp(sTabela, sNome, sValor);
    }`

Comment: Good to know. By the way, I just saw that you'd like to overwrite some default methods like hashCode() and equals(). I am not sure if that is a good idea. If you use it only for this one algorithm and you don't rely on those methods to be used elsewhere by the system, then consider defining your own methods for hash code and equality.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ArrayList` as a data structure. It is an unsynchronized data structure. In your question there are only read operations, so should not be a problem. However, overall in your program with so many unsynchronized lists, think about thread safety.

---

For `ArrayList` accessing element via iterator or via index is almost the same in terms of speed. However, that is not an official benchmark. You might consider trying your code with iterators also.

---

> I have several small arrayLists (800~1500) and for each one of those I
>   must verify if it contains all items from a evaluation arrayList in
>   the best possible time. Both the target arrayList (let's say, tSet)
>   and the evaluation arrayList (eSet) have 1 to 5 elements.

You have between 800 and 1500 array lists. I suppose you "are obliged" to use that datastructure.

You have 1 evaluation arrayList. Here I would consider a change maybe. I would use a Hash table/map as a data structure.
In average the search is faster. This is proven to be correct. The average time complexity for inserting/deleting/searching an element in a hash table/map is O(1). This means constant time in average. (The worst case is O(n), but in general we are interested in the average).

<s>"If a target list contains all items of an evaluation list" is equivalent to "all evaluation list items are in target list". In your example you loop through target list and compare, but you could as well loop through evaluation list and compare.</s>

> Now **assuming** that you always want to test whether **evaluation
>   list is a sub set of target list**. It is **better to loop through
>   evaluation list** and do the comparison as it is expected to have less
>   elements.

I will go through your code later. But there is one thing that I don't feel comfortable with:

> The conditions in your loop! Are you sure your algorithm works as expected?

Comment: You are absolutely right, the implementation of a hashmap would undoubtedly lead to marked increase in performance!

Comment: Hello @Elyasin. I have custom Equals and compareTo methods, so the objects obj1 = {sTabela = "1", sNome = "2", sValor="3"} and obj2 = {sTabela = "*AnyTable*", sNome = "*AnyAtrib*", sValor="*AnyValue*"} are to be considered equivalent. Wouldn't that be a problem using a hashSet?

Comment: @ Elyasin I suppose I could check for each element in eSet if I have a situation like obj2 or a regular object (like obj1) and then decide between using arrayList.contains() and hashSet.contains(), but wouldn't that kill my performance gain?

Comment: You simply retrieve the element from the HashSet. Then you can use that elements methods for compare for example. It is like using ArrayList, just expected to be faster. The "compare" would be part of the class that you want to compare I think.